# When I try to convert map value to list to print it, I got ''list' object is not callable' error

Tags: python-3.x, list, mapping

I'm learning map() function and some tutorial websites use map() and list like shown in code. They run the code but there is no error but I tried to run this code I got an error. Could you explain why?

```
list_a = [1,2,3]
list_b = ['one', 'two', 'three']
map_func = map(list_a, list_b)
map_func = list(map_func)
print(map_func)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-6ce25d7a149a> in <module>
      2 list_b = ['one', 'two', 'three']
      3 map_func = map(list_a, list_b)
----> 4 map_func = list(map_func)
      5 print(map_func)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Comment: what is an output that you are expecting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Python map() function** map() function returns a list of the results after applying the given function to each item of a given iterable
>   (list, tuple etc.)
>
> *Syntax :*  `map(fun, iter)`
>
> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable,
>   yielding the results. If additional iterable arguments are passed,
>   function must take that many arguments and is applied to the items
>   from all iterables in parallel. ...

Example:

```
# Return double of n
def addition(n):
    return n + n

# We double all numbers using map()
numbers = (1, 2, 3, 4)
result = map(addition, numbers)
print(list(result))
```

output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

your use of the function `map()` is wrong, you are probably thinking of `zip()` function

```
list_a = [1,2,3]
list_b = ['one', 'two', 'three']
map_func = zip(list_a, list_b)
map_func = list(map_func)
print(map_func)
```

output:

```
[(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three')]
```